# Converting HTML input characters to asterisks after a given time

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I tried for fun implementing a function that converts HTML input characters to asterisks after a given time. What do you think about my approach and how would you do it?

```js
const passwordEl = document.querySelector('#password');
const showPassEl = document.querySelector('#show-password');

const replaceAt = (string, index, replace) => {
  return string.slice(0, index) + replace + string.slice(index + 1);
}

const insertAt = (string, index, insert) => {
  return string.slice(0, index) + insert + string.slice(index);
}

const removeAt = (string, index) => {
  let strArr = string.split('');
  strArr.splice(index, 1);
  return strArr.join('');
}

let plainPass = '';
passwordEl.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const valueLen = passwordEl.value.length;
  if (e.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward') {
    plainPass = removeAt(plainPass, e.target.selectionStart);
  } else {
    plainPass = insertAt(plainPass, e.target.selectionStart - 1, e.data);
    if (showPassEl.checked) {
     passwordEl.value = plainPass;
     return;
    }
    // immediately convert previous character to * if user typed fast
    if (valueLen > 1 && passwordEl.value[valueLen - 2] !== '*') {
      passwordEl.value = replaceAt(passwordEl.value, valueLen - 2, '*');
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      passwordEl.value = replaceAt(passwordEl.value, e.target.selectionStart - 1, '*');
    }, 500);
  }
});

showPassEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  passwordEl.value = showPassEl.checked ? plainPass : '*'.repeat(passwordEl.value.length);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password">
<input type="checkbox" id="show-password">
<label for="show-password">show password</label>
```

Comment: i typed in `conteent`, pressed left arrow twice, backspace and then _show password_ gave me: `conteen` :)

Comment: Same issue if you tried to add characters in the middle, it will be added to the end haha ... I for some reason assumed that the user will always delete or add characters to the end. I'll try to fix that. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I fixed it. There are still some cases that are not handled though.

Comment: The `show passowrd` checkbox is not respected if I enable it and type the password

Comment: Fixed. I think the only issue now is if you typed fast between the password.

Comment: It still doesn't support most things you can normally do in a text input. You can't mark text and delete it, or ctrl+backspace to delete a word. You can't paste, cut, or drag and drop text. The delete key doesn't work.

Comment: Right. Feel free to share any better approaches in mind.

Comment: @Kruga Yeah, the code is pretty broken from the user perspective.

Comment: Hey @Kruga how about you post that as an answer instead of a comment? This seems to be highly valid criticism ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your time looking into my code. I'd appreciate it if you helped me by suggesting better approaches for writing a more robust version of this code.